# INT to hh:mm:ss tt in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I will have an integer calculated from datediff()

let's say.. it is..

```
declare @earliestTime int;
set @earliestTime=50000000;
```

I want to convert to hh:mm:ss tt

I have this code to convert that int to HH:mm:ss

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), (@earliestTime)/60)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), ((@earliestTime) % 60) ), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), ((@earliestTime) %60)*0), 2)
```

How can I modify it to hh:mm:ss tt (AM or PM)

I modified like this..

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), 
case 
when 
((@earliestTime)/60)<=12 
then 
((@earliestTime)/60) 
else 
(((@earliestTime)/60)-12)
end )

--CONVERT(varchar(6), case when((@earliestTime)/60)<=12 then (@earliestTime)/60 else ((@earliestTime)/60)-12)
+ 
':' 
+ 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), ((@earliestTime) % 60) ), 2)
+ 
':' 
+ 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), ((@earliestTime) %60)*0), 2
+
' '
+
convert(varchar(2),(case when ((@earliestTime)/60)<12 then 'am' else 'pm' end)))
```

But it gives me this error..

> Conversion failed when converting the
>   varchar value 'pm' to data type int.

I already convert 'pm' or 'am' to varchar(2). why the system still gives me that error?

How to make it correct or is there a better way?

Comment: what does the integer specify? seconds between two dates, hours, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't explain what your integer represents so it is difficult to give an answer.

It's best to use a proper data type for times.  I'd use `DATETIME` - it will allow to you to perform calculations, sort, and format as required.  Storing time as text is going to cause headaches later on.

Store a time by adding the time to the SQL epoch (1900-01-01 00:00:00), like so

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 50000, CONVERT(DATETIME, 0.0))
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 50000, CONVERT(DATETIME, 0.0))
```

Then format the `DATETIME` object accordingly.

- To get HH:mm:ss, use format 108.
- To get the AM/PM flag, use 100 and take the two rightmost characters.

Try the below:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = DATEADD(SECOND, 50000, CONVERT(DATETIME, 0.0))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, @date)%12) 
    + ':' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 108),5) 
    + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 100), 2)
```

I should also point out that you are working in a database, not a presentation layer.  There should be no need to worry about formatting dates and times in a database; it is about data storage and retrieval.  Presumably you are returning this time to an application or webpage to be put onto a screen, into a report or whatever - best practice is to keep the data as a complete `DATETIME` and let the top layer format it.  By converting to a `VARCHAR` you are just removing information and limiting yourself; no benefit, lots of cost.

Comment: you last 3 lines give me this.. 13:53:20PM isn't it suppossed to b 1:53:20 pm?

Comment: You're right - you need to play with the format strings to get the best combination.  This will work, although you might find a simpler combination `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, @date)%12) + ':' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 108),5) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 100), 2)`

Comment: You can cast your value into a date using this:
cast(@earliestTime/(24.*60*60) as datetime)

Comment: one side effect is.. your method is showing 0:00:00 PM instead of 12:00:00 pm

Comment: @william That's true.  SQL doesn't really have the required formatting patterns that you need - but you are using it for something that it was not designed for.  Why are you formatting to a string inside the database?

Comment: It's ok. I put a when statement to replace 00 with 12